# Display multiple checkbox value in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a project where I have to display check boxes and its values in a  table. That means in one Column Checkbox s will be there and and next column i have to display its value. I am very new to `jquery` so I tried but not getting proper output.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var values = [];
    $.each($('input:checked'), function(index, input) {
      values.push(input.value);
    });

    var str = values.join(',');
    $(".hello").html(str);

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>checkboxes</th>
    <th>Values</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name='cbox' value="red" class="theClass" />red
    </td>
    <td class="hello"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name='cbox' value="green" class="theClass" />green
    </td>
    <td class="hello"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name='cbox' value="blue" class="theClass" />blue
      <p></p>
    </td>
    <td class="hello"></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<table>
```

Comment: Your code works as I would expect it to but I am guessing your are looking for different results. Maybe give us an example of how it should be different?

Comment: Infront of red checkbox only red should display. But in my code all checked are displaying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the value to *all* table cells that have the class `hello`. You should instead select *only* the one next to the checkbox. You can do this by [navigating to the parent cell](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) and then the [next cell](https://api.jquery.com/next/).

One way to do this would be `$(this).parent().next(".hello")`

e.g.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  var val = this.checked ? this.value : "";
  $(this).parent().next(".hello").text(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>checkboxes</th>
    <th>Values</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name='cbox' value="red" class="theClass" />red
    </td>
    <td class="hello"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name='cbox' value="green" class="theClass" />green
    </td>
    <td class="hello"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name='cbox' value="blue" class="theClass" />blue
      <p></p>
    </td>
    <td class="hello"></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<table>
```